# PTIJ: Hansel & Gretel burning their house down for Biur Chametz

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Are Hansel and Gretel, who live in a [gingerbread house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel), forced to sell their house for Pesach each year (due to owning Chametz)? Are they always going to hotels for Pesach? Does this mean that by Purim, they aren't living at home, due to the Mitzvah of Bedikas Chametz being restricted to one's house/place of residence within 30 days of Pesach?

If they forget one year to book tickets to move away, do they burn their house down to be Mekayem Biur Chametz?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the plot of the story carefully. (Unless Wikipedia isn't describing this accurately.) The gingerbread house belongs to the witch. Even if Hansel and Gretel were both Jewish, they wouldn't be required to sell the house because they don't own it.

Comment: But let's assume that the witch died, and now they own the house.

Comment: OK ... Besides making up a Purim question, you want to rewrite the entire fairy tale, too?

Comment: It says, "They live happily ever after with the witch's wealth". This would indicate that they now owned the title to the gingerbread house! With their new real estate, comes the responsibility of Biur Chametz! @DanF

Comment: Possibly .... I'll give you benefit of doubt on that.